# Bootstrap 3 center styling attempt is failing

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the full [jsFiddle for my code](http://jsfiddle.net/7j9q1ye4/).

I am trying to center the footer. Notice that the main footer links are indented from their respective "Column Leaders" ("ONE", "TWO", "THREE" and "FOUR"); I still need that indentation to be preserved even after everything is centered.

Placing the `<center>` tags around the footer div does not do what I need...I need the 4 Column Leaders, plus the `<hr/>`, plus the copyright/privacy/service links centered; and furthermore, I need the column links (under the leaders) to be indented 4 - 5 spaces.

**Can anyone help provide me with the necessary CSS tweaks to accomplish my objectives here? I'm losing my mind trying to figure this out!**

In the back of my mind I'm worried that my JS might be throwing an error somehow and maybe causing the browser not to render correctly:

```
$('#fieldModePopover').popover({ 
    content: function() {
        return "Yahtzee!";
    }
});
```

Comment: Your Fiddle isn't with Bootstrap better this http://www.bootply.com/OZxIu62RET

Comment: You have many problems on your code please limit the question to ONE at post.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Danko (+1) - please see my edits and please consider removing the downvote if you are happy with them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 4 columns in footer and the whole footer should be centered.Please let me know if that is the case I will try to explain things then.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyApp</title>

    <!-- External CSS to include. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
}

/*
 *  Colors:
 *      Dark Blue:      rgb(12,66,144)
 *      Light Blue:     rgb(176,205,249)
 */

/*html, body {
    height: 100%;
}*/

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.rowc{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}

.colc{

    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align:left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
    margin-right:-4px;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    background: rgb(12,66,144);
    border: solid 1px rgb(12,66,144);
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    color: rgb(176,205,249);
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: rgb(176,205,249);
}

.nav .signin {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}

.footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.footer {
    color: rgb(176,205,249);
    background: rgb(12,66,144);
    border-top: solid 5px rgb(176,205,249);

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

.spacer {
    margin-top: -10px;
}

hr {
    color: rgb(176,205,249);
}

.right-pinned-col {
    position:absolute;
    right: 235px;
}

.field-mode {
    color: rgb(255,102,0);
}

.fieldModePopover{
    width:200px;
    height:250px;    
}

.field-mode-header {
    border: solid 3px rgb(255,102,0);
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Header and main nav. -->
            <!-- If in Field Mode, append a "field-mode-header" class to this nav element below. -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My<b>App</b></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Fizz&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Who we are</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">What we do (best)</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Demo</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Buzz&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Ask a question</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Apply for work</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Foo&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Bar</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a id="fieldModePopover" href="#" data-html="true"
                                data-content="In <b>Field Mode</b>, you may continue to use this app, however you are not connected to our backend. All data will be saved locally to your computer. To sync this data remotely you will need to sign back in and send it once you have a network connection."
                                rel="popover" data-placement="right"
                                data-original-title="<b>Field Mode is Activated</b>" data-trigger="hover">
                                <span class="field-mode glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="signin">
                            <a id="popoverData" href="#" data-html="true" data-content="<input class='form-control' placeholder='username'>" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Sign in to your account" data-trigger="click"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sign In | Register</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <!-- Page content. -->
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>My<b>App</b></h1>
                    <p>
                        The greatest app ever written by Smeeb.
                    </p>

                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer. -->


    <footer class="footer img-rounded">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row rowc">
                <div class="col-md-3 colc">
                    <b>ONE</b>
                    <div class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1-Minute Video</div>
                    <div class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;5-Minute Video</div>

                        <div class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Demo</div>

                        <div class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FAQ</div>                   
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 colc">
                    <b>TWO</b>

                        <div class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ask a Question</div>

                        <div class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Apply</div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 colc">
                    <b>THREE</b>

                        <div class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bar</div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 colc">
                    <b>FOUR</b>

                        <div class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Blog</div>


                        <div class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Social: <img src="fb.png" /></div>

                        <div class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wiki</div>

                        <div class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sitemap</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-3"><hr/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span>
                     Smeeb 3050
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 right-pinned-col">Privacy Policy | Terms of Service</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>



    <!-- Scripts to include. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="auditcloud.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```